# .objects.all() returns nothing

Tags: python, django

its my first time to ask hope I can find solution to my problem. Am trying to display the courses in an html page using objects.all() but it returns nothing and the page remain empty, even though records do exist in the database. I tried the same method for other pages and it worked, idk what am doing wrong here :(

in view.py

```
def viewCourse(request):
    corlist = Course.objects.all()
    #print(muffin)
    #course.count()
    context = {'corlist':corlist}
    return render(request, 'LogInApp/ViewCourse.html', context)
```

in model.py

```
class Course(models.Model):
    COURSES = (
        ('Data Structure','Data Structure'),
        ('Computer Network','Computer Network'),
        ('Web Design','Web Design'),
        ('Internet of Things','Internet of Things'),
        ('Artificial Intelligence','Artificial Intelligence'),
        ('Artificial Intelligence-Tut', 'Artificial Intelligence-Tut'),
    )
    course_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, choices= COURSES)
    fk_lecturer_id = models.OneToOneField(Lecturer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # foreign key
    date = models.DateField(max_length=20, null=True)
    time = models.TimeField(max_length=20, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.course_id, self.course_name)

    @property
    def lecturerid(self):
        return self.fk_lecturer_id.lecturerid
```

in ViewCourse.html

```
<table border="1" class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Course ID</th>
                        <th>Course Name</th>
                        <th>Course Lecturer</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Time</th>
                        <th width="100px"> </th>
                    </tr>
                    {% for co in corlist %}
                    <tr>
                        <td> {{ co.course_id }} </td>
                        <td> {{ co.course_name }} </td>
                        <td> {{ co.fk_lecturer_id }} </td>
                        <td> {{ co.date }} </td>
                        <td> {{ co.time }} </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </table>
```

Comment: Your code looks just fine. Could you please `print(corlist)` in your view to check if there are rly no entries?

Comment: wouldn't ```corlist``` be a dictionary?  i.e. ```{"corlist": corlist}```  and so in the template, wouldn't it be ```for co in corlist["corlist"]:```?  (tbh, not familiar with ```render```, as I use ```render_template``` most of the time)

Comment: @JSRB I did try `print(corlist)`, yet it returns nothing

Comment: @Zoe well than it is empty.. did you change the manager of your model? if not, please re-check if there are entries in the db...

Comment: @JSRB Hmm it's not empty though, I didn't change the manger as well. My other pages gets the data just fine in the same way, it's only this one

Comment: Did it print nothing or did it print `<QuerySet []>`? If it printed nothing then your view is not even running. You can confirm by printing some literal string `print("Hello")`. You should check your url patterns and confirm that the request is being routed to the view you think it is.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat nothing was printed, not even `<QuerySet []>`, will try thank you

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I didn't find any mistake in the url everything looks fine, but still not running